# Get access to FieldElements without ImplicitFieldConstructor

Tags: playframework, validation

We're trying to be consistent when we define our error messages for form validation / authorization, but we're finding it a bit hard to work with Play 2.0's @Constraints etc.

What we want is to be able to access each error (and it's relevant i18n-translation), preferably through an error object. This proved to be rather difficult however, as the errors (at least from @Constraint) are applied to their i18n-translations in the ImplicitFieldConstructor, which we don't really have much access to.

What we'd like to know is if there's a way to access all FieldElements of each field in a form without going through the ImplicitFieldConstructor? (hopelessly tried @helper.FieldElements)

of course we could just drop the entire @Constraints and just define our own validators and validation methods, but it seems kinda counter-intuitive since we want to use the framework for all that it's worth.

EDIT: Also, we tried this:

```
    @for((key, value) <- loginForm.errors) {
        @value.get(0)
    }
```

But that just gives us the messages (for instance 'error.required') rather than the i18n-translation.

**Edit**

We use this for now as a hack to fix it, but I'd like to find a better way of handling this.

```
    if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
        // TODO: find a better solution to handle this problem.
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<ValidationError>> entry : loginForm.errors().entrySet() ) {
            ValidationError oldError = entry.getValue().get(0);
            // applay i18n-translation to error message.
            ValidationError error = new ValidationError(oldError.key(),  Messages.get(oldError.message()), new ArrayList());
            entry.getValue().set(0, error);
        }
        return badRequest(index.render(loginForm));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option if you have access to the .java files you are trying to add validation to is in your Constraint to add the message = "Text" element. This would change the message displayed without you having to write your own custom validation.

```
@Required(message = "Your message here!")
public String someField;
```

Comment: We actually did that, but that sort of misses the point of the whoe i18n-translation as the message in @Required has to be a constant (and as such we can't use @Messages.get("").